# Devise wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) upon session_controller#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm trying to login with the default activeadmin email - admin@example.com and password - password but when i click login i get the error

```
 `wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)`


  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_flashing_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource) #ERROR SHOWING AT THIS LINE
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end
```

May i know what's going wrong ? This is the error i got in my terminal

```
Started POST "/admin/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-24 16:49:53 +0800
Processing by ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "admin_user"=>{"email"=>"admin@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Login"}
  AdminUser Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users"  WHERE "admin_users"."email" = 'admin@example.com'  ORDER BY "admin_users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "admin_users" SET "current_sign_in_at" = $1, "last_sign_in_at" = $2, "sign_in_count" = $3, "updated_at" = $4 WHERE "admin_users"."id" = 1  [["current_sign_in_at", "2014-07-24 08:49:53.235190"], ["last_sign_in_at", "2014-07-24 08:49:18.879844"], ["sign_in_count", 16], ["updated_at", "2014-07-24 08:49:53.236414"]]
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 85ms

ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (2 for 1):
  devise (3.2.4) app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:17:in `create'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:45:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.7.2.195) lib/new_relic/rack/error_collector.rb:55:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.7.2.195) lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:32:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.7.2.195) lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:27:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.7.2.195) lib/new_relic/rack/developer_mode.rb:45:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  clearance (1.3.0) lib/clearance/rack_session.rb:10:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
```

Comment: what version of devise are you using, and can you post the complete error with backtrace? Have you defined your own `sign_in` method anywhere in your app?

Comment: devise (3.2.4). Im using another gem - Clearance.Not sure if it would affect.

Comment: `clearance` also does authentication. This is a likely conflict.

Answer (score 2):

You've said you are using both `devise` and `clearance` in your app. Both gems handle authentication, and conflict with each other.

In particular, `clearance` defines a `sign_in` method that takes only one parameter:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance/blob/8d3958eb5fdc9b762df4788fd81793801940b754/lib/clearance/authentication.rb#L33

While `devise` defines one that takes two:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/b786c384d54a6365bdc6c0cf6068dc5325a301a9/lib/devise/controllers/sign_in_out.rb#L30

You should either remove clearance or devise from your app, as they perform the same task.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
sign_in(resource_name, resource)
```

with

```
sign_in(resource)
```

Comment: but i don't have the session_controller in my files. The params are in devise ssession_controller create action. Line #18 https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb

Comment: do you have the repo as opensource so I can take a look of it? it could be several things...

Comment: No i don't. I'm basically trying to login as an admin with the default email admin@example.com but then i got the error.