# Devise wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

[Existing issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924452/devise-wrong-number-of-arguments-2-for-1-upon-session-controllercreate)  There is an existing question and I am getting the exact error after upgrading to rails 4.2.0.

The above issue was a conflict between `devise` and `clearance` but I am not using `clearance`. I suspect that some of my gem is causing the problem.
Here is my code:

```
gemfile

source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem "figaro"
gem 'nokogiri'

gem 'bootstrap-editable-rails'
gem 'devise'
gem 'devise_token_auth' 
gem 'devise_invitable', '~> 1.3.3'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'redis'
gem 'switch_user', '0.9.4'
gem 'websocket-rails', '0.6.2'
gem 'twilio-ruby', '~> 3.11'

gem 'aasm'
gem 'acts_as_tenant'
gem 'activerecord-postgresql-adapter'
gem 'annotate', '>=2.6.0'
gem 'chronic_duration'
gem 'attribute-defaults'
gem 'groupdate'
gem 'hairtrigger'
gem 'money-rails'
gem 'nilify_blanks'
gem 'pacecar'
gem 'paranoid2'
gem 'schema_plus'
gem 'time_ago_in_words'
gem 'validates_timeliness', '~> 3.0'
gem 'spreadsheet'

gem 'client_side_validations', github: 'DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations'
gem 'client_side_validations-simple_form', github: 'DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations-simple_form'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'rails-timeago', '~> 2.0'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'slim-rails'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :github => 'seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails', :branch => :bootstrap3
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', '~> 2.2.3'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-calendar'

gem 'dust-rails', '0.4.0'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'gon'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'less-rails'
gem 'remotipart', '~> 1.2'
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails-confirm', github: 'bluerail/twitter-bootstrap-rails-confirm', branch: 'bootstrap3'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'paperclip', '~> 3.5.0'

gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'sinatra', '>= 1.3.0', :require => nil
gem 'whenever', :require => false

gem 'liquid'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.1'
  gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1'
  gem 'capistrano-ext'
  gem 'capistrano-rvm'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler'
  gem 'letter_opener'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'pry', '~> 0.10.0'
  gem 'brakeman', :require => false
  gem 'meta_request'
end

group :test do
  gem 'email_spec'
  gem 'minitest'
end
```

Comment: try removing `devise` , then do `bundle install` and then again install devise . Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: genius..wasted 12 hours on it, and this is what finally worked.
removed devise, closed the terminal. It is working perfectly fine. 
Thanks

Comment: Glad to know that helped you . I would be more glad if you can accept my answer below . thnx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all remove `devise` from your `application` .

Then do a `bundle install` .

And finally again , `install` devise .

This will work .

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Turbolinks, try updating the turbolinks gem. That fixed the issue for me after upgrading from Rails 4.1 to 4.2 and having this issue.